# Django when I try to search a form its value gets u'

Tags: django, unicode, get

I'm trying to do the search tutorial but I got an error where it shows that I searched for `u'foo'` instead of `foo`. If I just print the message with `'%s' % q` it shows just `foo`

```
def search(request):
   q = request.GET.get("q",None)
   if q:
       message = '%s' % q
       message = Envio.objects.get(destinatario=message)
   else:
      message = 'Empty'
    return HttpResponse(message)

def search_form(request):
     return render_to_response('envios/search_form.html')
```

Error:

```
Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  100.                     response = callback(request, *callback_args,     **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\mysite\envios\views.py" in search
  35.         message = Envio.objects.get(destinatario=message)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in get
  132.         return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in get
   347.                     % self.model._meta.object_name)

   Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /envios/search/
   Exception Value: Envio matching query does not exist.
```

And below that:

```
Request information

 GET
 Variable     Value
 q             u'102'
```

Comment: Please show the error. Where does the error occur?

Comment: Note that if you `print '%r' % q` you'll see the actual representation of the unicode string.

Comment: @Jaime - Is destinatario a field of Envio model?

Comment: When I use a shell to do an objetcs.get(id=something), it works.

Comment: @Jaime - Is destinatario string type or integer type. The error that you are getting is possible if types in query do not match. So instead of `message = '%s' % q` try `message = str(q)` or `message = int(q)` as may be applicable.

Comment: @Jaime - I'll edit my answer to include the updated information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u'' just means that the string is shown in unicode. Default encoding in django is unicode. Don't bother too much with u'', the actual result will always be the string between the single quotes.

For more info, look here. http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/

So the error that you are getting is possible if types in query do not match. So instead of

```
message = '%s' % q
```

try

```
message = str(q)
```

or

```
message = int(q)
```

as may be applicable.